# Convergence of series of the form $\sum 1/n^x$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Why the solution says $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n^{1.5}}$ converges? Does every series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n^{x}}$   converges to 0 except $1/n$ (harmonic Series)?

[image]

I found that after verifying a series with series convergence test, especially for comparison test and limit comparison test, I do not have a clear mind on verifying the series that I comparing is converge or diverge. Do I need to use the partial sum to test the convergence of series that I comparing every time?

Comment: For $\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{n^{1.5}}$, we can show convergence using the Integral Test (or Cauchy Condensation). After we have shown (same way) that $\sum \frac{1}{n^x}$ converges when $x\gt 1$, we can use these series for comparison.

Comment: Thanks @AndréNicolas. So does it mean that I have to check the convergence of the series that I used to compare with other convergence test? Is there any other handy way to do it?

Comment: We gather a collection of basic series that we show converge (or diverge). After that, most convergence/divergence questions, at least for series with positive terms, can be settled by Comparison or Limit Comparison.

Comment: Can you please give me some example of basic series? I just know Harmonic series is obviously diverges.

Comment: An important but often neglected fact is that if $\lim a_n$ does not exist, or exists but is $\ne 0$, then $\sum a_n$ diverges. For Comparison, we sometimes use geometric series, sometimes $p$-series $\sum \frac{1}{n^p}$. These are the main ones.

Comment: I understand that if lim an does not exist, or exists but is ≠0, then ∑an diverges. Is all the p-series converge to 0 where only the Harmonic series is the exceptional case?

Comment: $p$-series generally do not converge to zero. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/n^{2} = \pi^{2}/6$. You should be careful about distinguishing between the infinite sum and merely the limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n^{2}}$.

Comment: The $p$-series never converge to $0$. If $p\le 1$ they diverge, and if $p\gt 0$ they converge. A nice formula for what they converge to is only known in rare cases, most importantly when $p$ is an even positive integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When discussing series, avoid saying "series converges to ..."; this kind of statement is almost always misguided.

When discussing *sequences*, we talk about what their terms converge to. For example, $1/\sqrt{n}$ converges to $0$ as $n\to\infty$.

When discussing *series*, we could still think about what happens to individual terms, but this is not the main thing: the convergence of a series is a matter of their *partial sums*. The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/2^n$ converges, but it would be wrong to say that it "converges to $0$". Rather, the sequence of its terms $1/2^n$ converges to zero. The series itself converges and has sum equal to $1$.

In your examples: the sequence of terms $1/n^x$ converges to $0$ for any $x>0$.

But the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n^x$ converges only when $x>1$. And its sum is never $0$; it's some positive number which we don't necessarily know or perhaps even care about.

Comment: Thank you. That's useful information. How about arithmetic series? The series _1/n_ diverges, and I would have guessed that so would _1/2n_, or _1/Cn_ for arbitrary _C_. But I just learned today that the series _1/p_ (_p_ prime) diverges. Is there some lower limit here as there is with power series?